# Blender-osm Image Overlay URL

Tags: blender-osm

I was building a city in Blender using Blender-OSM. But instead of using "ArcGIS" and "MapBox" tokens, I decided to use "custom URL" overlay. But what's the URL? (What does he mean by URL) and how can I get a URL of a map overlay?
Thanks in advance! [image]